# Error when trying to create Kubernetes job

Tags: python, kubernetes, yaml

I've defined this method, it should create a Kubernetes job for me.

```
def make_job():
    job = client.V1Job()
    job.metadata = client.V1ObjectMeta()
    job.metadata.name = "process"
    job.spec = client.V1JobSpec()
    job.spec.template = client.V1PodTemplate()
    job.spec.template.spec = client.V1PodTemplateSpec()
    job.spec.template.spec.restart_policy = "Never"
    job.spec.template.spec.containers = [
        make_container()
    ]
    return job
```

However, it returns an error on this line.

```
job.spec = client.V1JobSpec()
```

Saying

```
ValueError: Invalid value for `template`, must not be `None`
```

I wonder if I am doing something wrong here, and if so, what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

I've solved the error with this change

```
job.spec = client.V1JobSpec(template=client.V1PodTemplate)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already figured out, it is not possible to construct a `Job.Spec` without injecting its `template`, something that is set on stone in the Job [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/).

> The .spec.template is the only required field of the .spec.
>
> The .spec.template is a pod template. It has exactly the same schema as a
>   pod, except it is nested and does not have an apiVersion or kind.

Taking a look onto the Python's Kubernetes Client implementation of the `V1JobSpec`, it's possible to verify that the `spec` property is marked as [non-optional](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/e057f273069de445a2d5a250ac5fe37d79671f3b/kubernetes/docs/V1JobSpec.md), contrary to the other properties.

So by constructing the `template` beforehand and injecting it while constructing the `JobSpec` does solve the issue:

```
job.spec.template = client.V1PodTemplate()
job.spec.template.spec = client.V1PodTemplateSpec()
job.spec.template.spec.restart_policy = "Never"
job.spec.template.spec.containers = [
    make_container()
]

job.spec = client.V1JobSpec()
```

Following this reasoning, it does seem weird that the same does not apply in a higher-scope to the `Spec` property of the `Job`, since it's a mandatory section of the definition of a Job object.

But taking a look once again to the [documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/e057f273069de445a2d5a250ac5fe37d79671f3b/kubernetes/docs/V1Job.md) of the client, it is possible to observe that the `Spec` property is marked as optional, which explains why we are able to create a `Job` instance, without having to inject the `Spec`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this as I now actually understand what I did wrong!